# How can I change the animation on a button in material UI?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use material UI in react and I want a button that doesn't have the animation that is a wave from the point of clicking the button to outside it like demonstrated [here](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/)

I instead, want it to have an animation that just fills in the entire button at once kind of like this button [here](https://miro.medium.com/max/648/1*PWT5q3FBrh6h7-Tb7TL-SA.gif) (not the loading animation, I need the button press to change the entire button's color at once rather than let the color change propagate throughout the button itself. I couldn't find a better example of the button press online, that's why I used this).

What customizations do I need to make to the makeStyles() function or are there any additional functions that I might need to create?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: this https://material-ui.com/components/progress/#progress ?

Comment: No, not like that, the exact button click animation right *before* it instead @dovigz

Comment: @programoholic I have tried looking into modifying the material ui animations, however, there's nothing I could find that would help me so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, not the one I was looking for, but turns out, there's a  prop called disableRipple that I was unaware of. It's close enough to what I wanted, so I will use that for my website. Thank you for contributing everyone!